# Printing precision of Numpy structured array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to set the print precision for a numpy structured array, but it does not seem to work.

```
H = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('x','float',2),('f','float')])
H['x']= np.random.uniform(0,1,(1,2))
H['f']= np.random.uniform(0,1)
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(H)
```

leaves

```
[([0.5928384015048476, 0.6187004067605606], 0.2981617279773586)]
```

not

```
[([0.593, 0.619], 0.298)]
```

as I expected. Printing each field does work, but I have many fields in my structured array and I don't want to have to print each one when monitoring the progress of my code.

Comment: print(H[0][0]) works, I can't remember how to get it to work on subelements

Comment: `print(H['x'])` also works (since `H['x']` is not a structured array), but it would be nice if `print(H)` used the precision set by `set_printoptions()`.  This might be a numpy bug.  You can create an issue here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues (hit the green "New issue" button).

Comment: The issue is now [open](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5606). I will post updates if I receive any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved in recent numpy versions:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5606